# How to read/write memory of your application in C++

Tags: c++, memory, process, activex

I want to read/write memory of an ActiveX object (allocated memory, not code).
How I can scan/read/write my application in memory?
Do I need to OpenProcess from my application to it self?

Thanks.

Comment: Vague question. What memory do you want to read exactly? For what purpose?

Comment: To access the memory of your process you need nothing but pointers. But a COM object may not expose the address of its actually data via the interface pointer it gives you. If you want to scan your own memory, you may need `VirtualQuery` to know what regions of memory are accessible.

Comment: I'm making an interactive mod for a flash applications. I need to get access to whole process memory as a memory scanner application will do only just for my application not for foreign one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VirtualQuery` to determine the allocated ranges of memory. Use `OpenProcess` and `ReadProcessMemory` to copy chunks of memory to a buffer that you control. Analyze the buffer contents.

Comment: Ok, so same procedure as a foreign process?